# SSRS - disabling Export functionality based on User

Tags: reporting-services, export

I have a report in SSRS that needs to disable the "Export" functionality based on who the User is.  Is this do-able?  And, is it possible to disable all Export options except the PDF option

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Upon research, I found the below URL that basically says you can't disable "Export" on a report by report basis....only pre server. Also, it looks like, when using the ReportViewer control on an aspx page, you can disable "Export" types. The author suggest that SSRS incorporate this in the Reports Manager. http://mikemason.ca/blog/2007/04/disabling-export-formats-in-reporting-services/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon research, I found the below URL that basically says you can't disable "Export" on a report by report basis....only pre server. Also, it looks like, when using the ReportViewer control on an aspx page, you can disable "Export" types. The author suggest that SSRS incorporate this in the Reports Manager.